No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options with Angular 17 and Firestore
I added angularfire to my angular 17 standalone component app via
ng add @angular/fire

which seemed to work and modified my app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
    enabled: !isDevMode(),
    registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
  }),

  provideFirebaseApp(() =>
    initializeApp({ "projectId": "myapp", "appId": "1:534543345345345", "storageBucket": "myapp.appspot.com", "apiKey": "mykey", "authDomain": "myapp.firebaseapp.com", "messagingSenderId": "534534534345345" })),
  provideAuth(() => getAuth()), provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ]
};

i added AngularFirestore to my component constructor but I get an error in console (app compiles):
ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)...

